# How do I allow/deny users based on their Identity in a simple MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roles

I created a new MVC application, and set the authorization to Identity.

When I run the boilerplate application with no changes, it says welcome mydomain\myuser top right.

I'd like to specify a list, perhaps in the web config, or in the code, of users that are allowed to use the system, so it's restricted to three accounts (or possible I will store a list in the database so it can be edited)

However I can't seem to find any information about how to do this. I thought that `[Authorize]` might be connected to a method that I can override, but it is hard to find information on Identity. I've only used other forms of authentication in the past, and every iteration of mvc seems to have a new way of doing things.

Any suggestions?

This is an ASP.NET MVC Web Application .NET 4.7.1 (not Core)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a role-based authorization. The simplest way is to add a specific role (like `"Admin"`) to the 3 accounts you're talking about. And then you can add the following attribute before your controller or action method :

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

You can find more information in [this tutorial](https://bitoftech.net/2015/03/11/asp-net-identity-2-1-roles-based-authorization-authentication-asp-net-web-api/).

Comment: It looks like this method relies on setting up the database and implementing quite a lot of code that isn't in the default implementation - is there no way to hard-code users, for example in the web.config?

Comment: I guess you could create your own custom `Authorize` attribute (inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute`) for that. In this custom attribute, you could retrieve hard-coded user names/ids from web.config and check if the current user is one of them.